# Plotting several Gaussian distributions in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am new with mathematica and I have found a problem.

How can I plot several Gaussian distributions using mathematica (same variance). For example, one with mean 2, other with mean 5 and other with mean 7.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use Plot Evaluate@Table and introduce a vector containing the means of the Gaussian distributions. Here is the code:

```
mu = {2, 5, 7};
sigma = 2;
Plot[Evaluate@
Table[PDF[NormalDistribution[mu[[i]], sigma], x], {i, 1, 
Length[mu]}], {x, -4, 15}]
```